# My player is getting stuck inside the wall in the 2D platforming game I am making in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, game-development

I am making a 2D platforming game in unity. For some reason, the player is getting stuck in the wall. I have used a **Tilemap** for the wall, then used **tilemap Collider 2D** with **composite collider**. The same thing works fine with the ground.

When I go left facing the wall, it behaves as expected:
[image]

When I release the left arrow button, it also shows the expected result:
[image]

But when I click right arrow next, the player gets stuck inside the wall:
[image]

and cannot get out:
[image]

Here is my player movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    
    [SerializeField] private float movement_speed = 2;
    [SerializeField] private float jump_power = 5;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;

    private Rigidbody2D rb_player;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb_player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        groundLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("ground");
        wallLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("wall");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        
        rb_player.velocity = new Vector2(x * movement_speed, rb_player.velocity.y);
        

        //flip the player
        if(x > 0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }

        else if(x < -0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }


        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded())
        {
            jump();
        }


        anim.SetBool("run", x != 0);

        anim.SetBool("jump", !isGrounded());


        print("wall: "+isTouchingWall());
        print("ground: "+isGrounded());
        
    }


    private void jump()
    {
        rb_player.velocity = new Vector2(rb_player.velocity.x, jump_power);
        anim.SetTrigger("jump_trigger");
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        // {
        //     grounded = true;
        // }
    }

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, .2f, groundLayer);
        return raycastHit.collider != null;
    }


    private bool isTouchingWall()
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, new Vector2(transform.localScale.x,0), .1f, wallLayer);
        return raycastHit.collider != null;
    }
}
```

It would be nice if anyone can help me as I am a complete beginner in game development with unity.

Comment: How is your player's collider set up? My hunch is that the collider is off center/uneven, so when it gets flipped with `Transform`, it ends up partially clipped into the wall, and Unity relocates it inside.

Comment: @MattEng yes, you are right. The player portion in the sprite was to the left and so was the collider. So, when the player flipped, the collider went inside the wall.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

Your [pivot point](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html) of your player (where your player script is attached) isn't centered like your collider. Because of this, your box collider is being flipped like a page from a book and it lands inside the wall.

**To fix it**

Make sure that your player pivot point is the same as the center of your BoxCollider2D. This way, your collider won't "teleport" from right to left and bypass walls.

**Other tips**

I see some beginner's mistakes in your code, so even if you manage to fix your issue, I highly recommend to follow the next tips:

- All [physic based code](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-use-fixed-update-in-unity/#:%7E:text=While%20Fixed%20Update%2C%20which%20is,based%20functions%20in%20Fixed%20Update.) (jump, movement, etc.) should go inside `FixedUpdate()` method and use `Time.deltaTime` or `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to keep the same speed (for movement and jump) among computers.
- Use the proper [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), your variables should be camel case, no underscores. Methods (and Classes) should always start with a capital letter in C# (PascalCase).

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I figured out I had an asymmetric sprite with transparent bg covering most of the space, I trimmed the sprite and now the flipping works fine. And thanks for the tips, I will follow the conventions from now on.